# Inserting PHP variables into MySQL query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have some source code for a Payroll Management System that I am altering to use for an Overtime management system. I altered a MySQL select query to filter the employees based on the selected department. Now I am trying to pass the value of the "Department" drop down list into the SELECT query that is being ran (WHERE department_id = ?). I tried following some tips and code from other posts, but they have not worked so far. I try running the code, but get an error that says "Commands out of sync..." on line 27 ($result = $employee->get_result();). I am not sure if my code is wrong, or if it is trying to execute before the department drop down list has been selected?

This is how I am wanting the code to work:

1. Select a department from the Department drop down list. (Starting line 6 in the code)
2. The value of the department drop down list is passed into the Employee drop down list SELECT query, which shows the user only employees for the selected department. (Around line 24 of the code)

   ```php
   <?php include 'db_connect.php' ?>
   <?php ?>
   <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
   <form action="" id="employee-overtime">
       <div class="row form-group">
           <div class="col-md-4">
               <label for="" class="control-label">Department</label>
               <select id="department" class="borwser-default select2"> <!-- This section 
   populates the Department drop down list -->
                   <option value=""></option>
                   <?php 
                   $department = $conn->query("SELECT department_id, name FROM employee INNER 
   JOIN department on department.id = employee.department_id");
                   while($row = $department->fetch_assoc()):
                   ?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $row['department_id'] ?>"><?php echo 
   $row['name'] ?></option>
                   <?php endwhile; ?>
               </select>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
               <label for="" class="control-label">Employee</label>
               <select id="employee_id" class="borwser-default select2"> <!-- This section 
   populates the Employee drop down list -->
                   <option value=""></option>
                   <?php 
                   $employee = $conn->prepare("SELECT *,concat(lastname,', ',firstname,' 
   ',middlename) as ename FROM employee WHERE department_id = ? order by concat(lastname,', 
   ',firstname,' ',middlename) asc");
                   $result = $employee->get_result();
                   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):
                   ?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['ename'] . ' | '. 
   $row['employee_no'] ?></option>
                   <?php endwhile; ?>
               </select>
           </div>
   ```

[image: Screenshot of web app]

[image: Screenshot of code]

Comment: That error should only happen if you execute another query before you've processed all the results of a previous query. But that doesn't happen here.

Comment: @Barmar Not only, but most commonly. Queries can be out of sync for many reasons. In this case, the fetching happens before execution, which causes out of sync error.

Answer (score -1):

You're getting the error because you're missing a `bind_param()` statement that provides a value for the `?` in `$conn->prepare(...)`.

```
$employee->bind_param('s', $selectedDepartment);
```

Which brings up the question where you're going to get `$selectedDepartment`.

Your script doesn't seem to reflect the fact that when the page loads for the first time, there is no selected department. So there can be no select box listing employees of that department.
Also, the user may submit the form with no department selected because the first option is `<option value=""></option>`.

Only after you submit the form with your department choice, can you read it on the server in `$_GET[]` array. For that, add some `name` to the department SELECT box. (attribute `id` is not used for this.)

```
<select name="department" id="department" class="borwser-default select2">
```

Then you'll be able to read the selected department in `$_GET['department']`.

So to put all this together, first add `if (!empty($_GET['department'])) {}` statement around the area that shows employee select box:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['department'])) {
?>
<div class="col-md-4">
       <label for="" class="control-label">Employee</label>
...
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Then add `bind_param()` after the employee query:

```
$employee = $conn->prepare("SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE department_id = ? order by ...");
$employee->bind_param('s', $_GET['department']);
$result = $employee->get_result();
```

Comment: what about execute?

Comment: I made the changes you recommend (Petr 'PePa' Pavel) (and also removed the blank "option value="" " code so that the drop down list value would be populated from the DB query upon loading). Now when I try to run this section of code, the "Employee" drop down list does not appear. Do I need to POST the Department value somehow, or does the GET command not require that? I am wanting the selection from the "Department" drop down list to be set as the value of the ? in "department_id = ?" of the SELECT query for the Employee drop down list.

Comment: I added the execute command above the get_result line and that removed the error. I removed the `if (!empty...)` code and the drop down list for Employee came back. Now I just have to figure out why it doesn't have any values to choose from in the drop down list.

Comment: During the first execution, the user didn't select a department yet so there is no $_GET['department']. Only after the user clicks submit button and the page gets to run for the second time, with ?department=xyz is $_GET['department'] populated with xyz.

Comment: The user cannot press the Submit button until they have selected an employee (which they can’t do since the drop down list is blank, since the department hasn’t been applied yet). Is there a way to make a “refresh” button (or automatically refresh after the user selects a department value) that posts the value of department?

Comment: No - the user must submit the selected department and only then they can submit the form for the second time to submit the selected employee. The information about the selected department must somehow get from the browser to the server so that your PHP code gets its employees. The only way to avoid submitting the form is to use JavaScript and AJAX which is quite more complicated.